# C# - send variables as linux commands over ssh

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I'm trying to get user input into a string variable and send it to my Linux server using ssh and C#.
I'm using the [ssh.net](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) library and I want to pass the variable's value into a text file on the server, but I can't send it together with the echo command.
Is there any other way to do it??

Here is the code :

```
using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
{
client.Connect();
string message = Console.ReadLine();
var mycommand = client.RunCommand("echo message >> file.txt");
client.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently passing "message" as a string. All you need to do is append the contents of "message" variable instead,

```
using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
{
client.Connect();
string message = Console.ReadLine();
var mycommand = client.RunCommand("echo " + message + " >> file.txt");
client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the string... Use: "echo \"" + message + "\" >> file.txt"

Comment: interpolation make everything cleaner: $"echo \"{message}\" >> file.txt"